# If range A1:E1 is empty copy F1:J1 over

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a project that uses a program that forces me to essentially merge two ranges into one. What I need is something like a conditional statement that will check if the range A1:E1 is empty, if so copy F1:J1 over A1:E1 (and do this for all rows). If it is easier to simply create a whole new range in `K1:O1` as opposed to `copying over` existing cells, that works too.

This is a snippet of what part of the spreadsheet looks like now...

[image]

My goal is to simply merge all addresses into one large range of cell separated data with no empty cells to the right of every row.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to do this with a formula or VBA code? If VBA, then what code do you have currently?

Answer (score 3):

To do this without VBA code:

- Highlight columns A:E, but not the entire columns. To select just the data, scroll to the bottom-right corner of the data (column E), click into the last cell and press Ctrl-Shift-Home.
- Press Ctrl-G for the GoTo dialog and click the Special.. button. Choose blanks.
- Type = then press the right-arrow five times, to move to column F (of the current row).
- Press Ctrl-Enter to fill this formula in all the blank cells.
- Highlight A:E again and use Copy/ Paste Special, Values to replace the formulas that you have just created.
- Delete columns F:J.

However, you will not be able to do this if there are other blank cells in the region, or if there are any other formulas that you need to keep. (Well, you can do it even if the data contains some miscellaneous blank cells, as long as there is nothing five columns over for these cells.)